# Where to start? Delphi Tethering example not working

Tags: delphi, tethering

I'm stumped. I built the "BDShoppingList" example with 10.1 (Berlin). I ran the server on my Win8 machine then I compiled and ran the Win32 client on the same machine and it worked fine. Then I tried running the client on my Android phone and it would not connect so I tried running the client on my Win7 desktop and it also could not connect. All devices are on the same subnet and all have full access. I got the Windows query asking me if I want to allow the apps through the firewall and OK'd them all. I checked the firewall settings and the apps appear there and have permission (local network).

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Have you ensured that the firewall permits access in both directions, outbound *and* inbound?

Comment: We tried a few years back and could never make it work reliably. We finally switched to using the Indy TIdHttpServer and TIdHttp to talk back and forth between the desktop and mobile device. The time needed to manually set things up was far less then we sent trying to figure out why the tethering was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Malcolm Groves has nice series of [articles](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1842) about App Tethering.

TTetheringManager.AutoConnect takes optional parameters. Maybe length of time to wait for a response to discover other TTetheringManagers is too short. Could you lengthen the timeout?

Comment: I was pretty excited about this until I got to the last article where he finally gets to the question of ways to connect other than AutoConnect. Unfortunately, it seems he never got around to posting that information.